# finding matches for part words in SOLR

Tags: solr, filter, lucene, stringtokenizer, solr-query-syntax

I have a field with value of "holmes@sible.com"
I want get back this field If I search for "sible".
I use ngrams filter, which would help only if the string was "sible@holmes.com"
Which filters/tokenizers should I use for such a thing (pretty much the LIKE in sql).

Comment: Should it match if you search for "sib"?

Comment: yes, it should, although three letters is the smallest token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EdgeNGramFilterFactory would help only if the string was "sible@holmes.com" but NGramFilterFactory will get what you want with "holmes@sible.com" too.